# Функциональный график в html Js как?

Tags: javascript, html

Наверняка есть готовые библиотеки для построения графиков, например google chart
Но мне не хватает функциональности или я не знаю как это сделать.
Во первых мне нужны свечи, как на форексе и нужен масштаб / сжатие графика мышкой.
Мне это нужно, чтобы вывести туда график валют и поставить свои метки или вывести второй график параллельно в той же системе координат.

Какая библиотека поможет мне такое реализовать?

Comment: http://www.flotcharts.org/ много чего умеет

Comment: вопрос еще актуален?

Comment: да, если можешь что то предложить пиши

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотерка `Chart.js` . Вот ссылка на сайт: http://www.chartjs.org/